# Do math on output of cat

Tags: bash, shell, bit-manipulation, cat

I have a single byte, 0x1, inside t.data.

How would I read that file to perform bitwise math on it's contents in POSIX shell?

`echo $((1 << 1))`

gives 2, but

`echo $(($((cat t.data)) << 1))`

and `var d=$(< t.data); echo $(("$d" << 1))`

fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIX sh and Bash are not suitable for processing binary data, but you can use `printf` to convert back and forth between bytes and integers:

```
# Read the ascii value of the first byte
num=$(printf "%d" "'$(head -c 1 < t.data)")
echo "The decimal representation of the first byte is $num"

# Do some math on it
num=$(( (num << 1) & 0xFF ))
echo "After shifting by one, it became $num"

# Write back the result via an octal escape
oct=$(printf '%03o' "$num")
printf "\\$oct" > t.data
```

Comment: Thanks. Why is the apostrophe on that second line necessary? Also, why does cat not work here?

Comment: Because that is how you convert a char to it's ASCII value. (see man bash under `printf`)

Comment: @Christian All numbers in sh/bash are numerical ascii strings. The byte `0x01` is a control character and not a valid ASCII integer.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #71](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071) for more about converting character values to/from decimal and hex.